# How do I fill in the foreign key fields in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a table named `Pictunes` which has a column named `post_creator`. Within this table there's a column containing integer values (foreign keys) representing the `id` column in another table called `Users`.

There's also a `username` column within the `Users` table. I want to fill in the foreign keys (within the `post_creator` column of `Pictunes`) with this value, so the `post_creator` will be the `username` instead of the integer within the view. I'm not trying to change the database data.

I'm having a really hard time figuring out what to refer to this problem as, let alone find answers for it. I'm using PSQL and Laravel 5.1. Thanks!

Update, Here are my models and database columns:

`Pictune` Model »

```
namespace Pictunes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Pictune extends Model {
    /**
     * Mass assignable properties
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'post_creator',
      'image_name',
      'audio_name'
    ];

    /**
    * Pictunes have only one post creator
     */
    function creator() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Pictunes\User', 'pictune_creator', 'post_creator', 'pictune_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Pictunes have multiple tags
     */
    function tags() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('Pictunes\Tag')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

`User` Model »

```
namespace Pictunes;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
  AuthorizableContract,
  CanResetPasswordContract {
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     *  Mass assignable properties
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'selfie_name'
    ];

    /**
     * Encrypt the password before sending it to the database
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPasswordAttribute($to) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($to);
    }

    /**
     * Make the email value lower case
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setEmailAttribute($to) {
        $this->attributes['email'] = strtolower($to);
    }

    /**
     * Each user has many Pictunes
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    function pictunes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Pictunes\Pictune', 'pictune_creators', 'id', 'post_creator');
    }
}
```

Database tables »

[image: Database tables]

`pictunes` columns »

[image: <code>pictunes</code> columns]

`users` columns »

[image: <code>users</code> columns]

Update, is there anything else I can do to make this easier to answer? I feel like the best solution at this point would be to use an SQL statement because it seems that Eloquent can only provide this functionality through a pivot table which is unnecessary and overboard.

Comment: Have you set up the relations in your models?

Comment: I've added them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use relationships through Eloquent. Make sure you pass the extra parameters to the relationship in your models like `return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'city_id')`. You'd want to change the `'city_id'` part to correspond with your column names if you didn't follow the convention. That applies to whatever relationship you're using but you'll want to make sure you know which one goes where because I think the extra parameters differ for each method.